# How add Reporter.log() to log on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, testng

How can I add Reporter.log() on Jenkins log?

I write my test in java and used TestNG.

I try import:

`import org.testng.Reporter;`

next write method:

```
        Reporter.log("Click on button next");
        click(btnNext);
        return this;
    }
```

and write test:

```
    public void shouldPageChangeAfterClick(){
        mainPage
                .launch()
                .clickOnBtnNextPage()
                .assertThatPageIsCorrect();
    }
```

Next I run test on Jenkins from pom.xml, test is failed, but I don't see Reporter.log() in log on Jenkins.

What should I do to display Reporte.log() on Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reporter.log() method is to log the passed string to the HTML report. It will not print in any console or log file. You have to use different logger api to get the same in Jenkins console. Log4j will be helpful in this case.